# Directory exist if [-d "$/root/folder" ]; is not working

Tags: shell

I need to create a directory in root directory of Linux if it's not already present in it.So i am using the if [-d "$/root/folder" ]; but it's going to else part even if directory exist. Please help with this. Below is the code-

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ -d "$/root/folder" ];then
   echo "folder file already exist"
else
   echo "Settings in progress" \
&& mkdir folder   \
&& chmod 7777 folder \
&& cd folder \
&& mkdir FolderConnector \
&& chmod 7777 FolderConnector \
&& cd FolderConnector \
&& mkdir ClientInput \
&& mkdir ClientOutput \
&& chmod 7777 ClientInput \
&& chmod 7777 ClientOutput \
&& cat /home/data/RTV/file2 >>/etc/exports \
&& exportfs -r \
&& exportfs \
&& echo "Settings completed successfully."  
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do :

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e

if [ -d "/root/folder" ]; then
    echo "folder file already exist"
else
    echo "Settings in progress"
    mkdir folder   
    chmod 7777 folde
    cd folder
    mkdir FolderConnector 
    chmod 7777 FolderConnector 
    cd FolderConnector 
    mkdir ClientInput 
    mkdir ClientOutput 
    chmod 7777 ClientInput 
    chmod 7777 ClientOutput 
    cat /home/data/RTV/file2 >>/etc/exports 
    exportfs -r 
    exportfs 
    echo "Settings completed successfully."
fi
```

- `set -e` stop the script on the first error
- you had a `$` character in your test

Comment: Thanks Gilles. Code is working fine now. i figured out that ,was creating directory in home directory but in code i was checking it in root directory